# Arduino: ARM, MCU, SoC and RTOS

Tags: arduino-due

I'm trying to understand the relationship between embedded RTOSes, SoCs and chip architectures. Specifically, I have a hobby project that would involve me writing a real-time, embedded application for the [embox RTOS](https://github.com/embox/embox), and use Arduino hardware for my proof of concept/prototype. Then, budget permitting, I'd like to port that app to run on another, non-Arduino ARM-based system.

My *understanding* is that ARM is the chip architecture (a conceptual design, really), and that Arduino simply implements this design, and is also a "system on a chip" because it has other things (USB ports, GPIO pins, etc.) that make it more of a computer than just a MCU.

My *understanding* is that if embox runs on ARM, which they claim it does, then at some point in the future I can take my application and run it on another ARM-based system without any real headache/pain.

Is my understanding of: ARM, Arduino, MCU, SoC and embox/RTOS correct? If not, please clarify/correct me! If so, what sort of considerations *would* have to be made when porting my app to another ARM system in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that ARM is the chip architecture (a conceptual design, really),

ARM is the CPU core architecture used in the Atmel SAM3X MCU family. The MCU is the CPU plus all of the facilities (PWM, ADC, DAC, DMA, etc.) that are implemented in order to allow the CPU to interact with external circuitry.

> and that Arduino simply implements this design,

Most appropriately, "Arduino" is the IDE and the software libraries that come along with it, plus the specifications and connector layout of the various pieces of Arduino hardware.

> and is also a "system on a chip" because it has other things (USB ports, GPIO pins, etc.) that make it more of a computer than just a MCU.

"SoC" is exactly what it says on the tin: it's an entire system on a single chip. The Due is not a SoC, since it's a full board. The BCM2835 found on the RPi is a SoC. The SAM3X is a MCU, since it still requires more than just connectors to become a full "system".

> My understanding is that if embox runs on ARM, which they claim it does, then at some point in the future I can take my application and run it on another ARM-based system without any real headache/pain.

Provided that embox runs on the new system and that your application can be compiled for it.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams (+1) - a quick followup question for you: when you say that Arduino is "*...the IDE...software libraries...plus the specifications/connector layout for the various pieces of hardware*", can you provide a concrete example of each? I'm just not seeing the forest through the trees there... For instance what kind of software library are you talking about? What kind of connector layout, etc.?Thanks again!

Comment: All the libraries that come with the IDE; EEPROM, Ethernet, GSM, LiquidCrystal, etc. As for the connectors, everything on a board that isn't actual electronics that allows e.g. a shield to connect.